# Req.isAuthenticated turns to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

When I log in I'm authenticated but when I switch to another page req.isAuthenticated returns false and I'm on login panel. The second thing is when I log in I keep getting an error "can't set headers after they are sent". Here is my code:

```
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.end();
  } else {
    return res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
module.exports = (app, passport) => {
  app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local-login", 
    (err, user, info) => {
        if(!user) {
          res.render("index", { message: "Wrong password or login!" })
        } else {
          req.login(user, (error) => {
            if (error) return next(error);
            console.log("AUTH: ", req.isAuthenticated()) <--- RETURNS TRUE
            return res.render("map", { name: user.name });
          });
        }
      })(req, res, next);
  });
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.render("index"); // load the index file
  })
  app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    return res.render("index"); // load the index file
  })
  app.get("/map", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    return res.render("map");
  });
  app.get("/vehicles", isLoggedIn,  (req, res) => {
    return 
  });
  app.get("/settings", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render("settings");
  });
  app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Login page will of course give you `req.isAuthenticated` `true` because you are just authenticated by `passport` middleware.

Passport will return `req.isAuthenticated` `true` until you are not getting logged out and it will set req.isAuthenticated false when you hit `/logout` route

So maintaining the state of user you have to use sessions for storing state of 
application.

find below link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

you are getting "can't set headers after they are sent". because you are returning response twice. one that is after `req.isAuthenticated()` getting turn true and second is like you are again rendering a `map` page.

so instead of `return res.end()` you should have to use `next()`

```
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = true;
    res.locals.user =req.user; 
    next(); //If you are authenticated, run the next
  } else {
    return res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining but didn't help. After logging in everything is ok, but when I click on for example map, my req.session is like reset